# Can not add new languages in OpenCart 2.2.0.0. The "code" dropdown only has "en-gb" value

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

I am trying to localize a new OpenCart website. I've download the language in question and extracted it under /catalog/language/[xx] (the two letter lang code of the custom language).

However, when I go to Gear menu->Localization->Languages and click "Add new":

[image]

The "Code" dropdown only has the "en-gb" value:

[image]

Adding another language with the same "Code" is impossible, because it generates an error.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, instead of unzipping everything from the language pack archive under `category/language/[xx]` I had to unzip the individual directories from the language pack under:

- `/admin/language/[xx]/`
- `/catalog/language/[xx]/`
- `/install/language/[xx]/`

The lang pack's .zip file was neatly organized in this subfolder structure, but I overlooked this fact. I hope this is useful information for future searchers.

[image]